# Magento customer/invoice/order id format

Tags: php, magento, format

Is there anybody who is able to tell me how to change the format of id's in Magento?

I would like this format for invoice ID's: E-YYMM-#ID

```
Example: E-1310-028

Where: E- = standart prefix
       1310 = year + month
       028 = invoice id

Same for customers:
       E-005
       E-006
       E-007
```

I know this is tricky, but is there anybody who knows how to do this?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override increment_id value. Because you would like to use real invoice_id and real customer_id the first solution in my mind is you need to override it in _afterSave() method in resource model. For invoices f.e. you can override Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Invoice model in your local module (don't edit core files!) with methods _beforeSave() and _afterSave():

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $this->_useIncrementId = false;

    return parent::_beforeSave($object);
}

protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    if (!$object->getIncrementId()) {
        $newIncrementId = "E" . date("-ym-") . $object->getId();
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->update(
            $this->getMainTable(),
            array('increment_id' => $newIncrementId),
            'entity_id = ' . $object->getId()
        );
    }

    return parent::_afterSave($object);
}
```

For customers logic may be a little bit different but the idea is the same.
Hope it works for you ;)